# descendant selector

Tags: css

My idea of css below is next: will match all img elements with a class attribute that contains the value "left" and descendant of p element. Is that correct?

```
p img.left  { float: left; margin: 0.9em 0.9em 0.9em 0; padding: 0; }
```

Comment: have you tried it and something went wrong?

Comment: i am trying to create a theme based on existing one but unable to find such item in html output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's perfectly correct; your selector will [match *both* `img` elements](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/F3AEJ/3/):

```
<p>
    <img class="left" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nightlife" />
    <span><img class="left" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature" /></span>
</p>
```

You could, if you wanted to select only the first-level `img.left` descendants of the `p` tag:

```
p > img.left {
    /* CSS */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/F3AEJ/).

This will *not* match the `img` within the contained `span`.

Similarly, you could match only the `img` within the `span`:

```
p span img,
p span > img,
span img,
span > img {
    /* CSS */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/F3AEJ/1/).

References:

- [CSS Selectors, from the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

```
p img.left  {}
```

**HTML:**

```
<p>
   <img class="left" /> * MATCHES THIS *
   <img /> * NOT THIS *
</p>
<div>
   <img class="left" /> * NOT THIS *
   <img /> * NOT THIS *
</div>

<p>
    <img class="left" /> * MATCHES THIS *
    <img /> * NOT THIS *
    <span>
        <img class="left" /> * ALSO MATCHES THIS *
        <img /> * NOT THIS *
    </span>
</p>
```

With `p > img.left  {}` it will not match the `img` inside the `div` thats inside the `p`

Comment: A `div` is not a valid child of a `p` element; therefore [no CSS rule will style, or affect, an `img` within a `div` within a `p`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/F3AEJ/2/).

Comment: LOL this is very true.  Not sure what I was thinking.  Fixing now.